# Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between the left-hand side and right-hand side of a diff/compare-two-files editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, diff

I love using VS Code with the vscode-vim extension as I can do most editing without the mouse. But whenever I'm looking at a diff view (by clicking a file with changes in the SCM/git pane) or an editor that's comparing two files (by running "Compare Active File With..." command), I need to use the mouse to switch between the left and right sides (i.e. the "old" and "new" versions of the change). This is annoying because I frequently compare two files and want to merge them by copying segments with changes from one file to the other, which needs me to switch back and forth in the compare view. Does anyone know if there's a keyboard shortcut, or a command I can bind a new keyboard shortcut to, for this?

Comment: I think this is related to the shortcuts to switch between **editor groups**. It works when splitting the editor left and right, but it does not work with diff's, probably because one side is read-only. Maybe a feature-request?

Comment: I have wanted this feature for a while now. For some reason, "View: Focus Right Editor Group" works in switching focus from the left to the right editor, yet when focused on the right editor, "View: Focus Left Editor Group" does nothing. The other similar commands (i.e. focus previous editor, first editor) have no effect either.  Also, in response to above comment: the left and right diff's are both read/write.

Comment: So only have shortcut for moving from left to right - by either "View Focus First Editor Group" (`Ctrl-1`) or "View: Focus Right Editor Group". (VS Code 1.46.1 on Windows)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit (Nov 11, 2020, thanks to @Mark):**

`workbench.action.compareEditor.focusPrimarySide`, `workbench.action.compareEditor.focusSecondarySide` and `workbench.action.compareEditor.focusOtherSide` have been added to VS Code. Should be in v1.52

---

It's an official feature request now, so please upvote it if you want to see this in VS Code:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95068

Answer (score 1):

while changing focus the cursor resets to the previous state for both sides. I found this really annoying. The following keybind resets the cursor to center of the current view while changing focus.

Note: The multi-command extension is required for this.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command

```
"key": "alt+1",
"command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
"args": {
  "sequence": [
    "workbench.action.compareEditor.focusOtherSide",
    {
      "command": "cursorMove",
      "args": {
        "to": "viewPortCenter"
      }
    }
  ]
},
"when": "textCompareEditorActive"
```

Answer (score 1):

See the `compareEditor` commands in @psquid's answer if the you are doing a **compare** between two files.  But if you are doing a diff - like by clicking on a changed file in the SCM/git view, then you need this new command:

```
Diff Editor: Switch Sides    // there is no default keybinding
diffEditor.switchSide
```

For this to work, you need to have this setting enabled:

```
Diff Editor > Experimental: Use Version 2
```

That is enabled by default in the Insiders Build v1.81, but is disabled in Stable v1.80 (and may also be disabled by default in Stable v1.81 due out early August 2023).